# Getting a Character Representation of Hexadecimal Digit (Creating a char* to display a Hex Value)

Tags: c, string, hex, ascii, representation

I've been looking for about half an hour and I can't seem to find a good process for setting up a char* that points to a string of characters which correspond to a Hexidecimal string.

Just to clarify, what I'm trying to do is take a Hexidecimal string, (say 0x0043 for example) and end up with a character string that contains "0x0043" that can be used on an LCD display or written to a file easily.

I'm sure there is a fairly easy way to do this, but have found no leads. Anyone in the know on this?

EDIT: This is for an embedded project, so I don't have any access to predefined functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert 1 hex digit at a time.

```
void foo(unsigned x) {
  char buf[2 + sizeof x * 2 + 1];
  char *p = &buf[sizeof buf - 1];
  *p-- = '\0';
  do {
    *p-- = "0123456789ABCDEF"[x&15];
    x >>= 4;
  } while (p != &buf[1]);
  *p-- = 'x';
  *p = '0';
  // Use p
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_HEX_LENGTH 10

int main()
{
       int x = 0x0043;
       char str[MAX_HEX_LENGTH];

       sprintf(str, "0x%.*x", MAX_HEX_LENGTH, x);
       printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
0x0000000043
```

You can change the value MAX_HEX_LENGTH to anything you want.

Comment: Oh yeah, that was just a random value I picked up. It should ideally depend on the size of integer you are using. As you mentioned, (2 + sizeof(int) + 1)

Comment: Yes, (2 + sizeof(int) * 2 + 1)

Comment: Almost. I don't have access to the stdio header as this is for an embedded system display. As a result I can't make use of sprintf().